# html2canvas zoom problem on capture image when printing

Tags: printing, html2canvas

I'm trying to print an element with html2canvas. But it gives empty space from left and it shows like below image. There isn't any scroll in the page. I tried lots of solution but nothing works.

my html code:

```
 <div *ngIf="journeyAnalizeData" class="row rowmargin0">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-12 gridPadding">
                <div id='printArea'>
                    <table id="tableList" class="table-list">
                        <tr>
                            <td
                                style="text-align: center; color:Black;background-color:White;border-style:None;width:247px;vertical-align:Top;padding: 0px;">
                                <div id="container" class="container">
                                    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; display:flex; flex-direction: column;">
                                        <div class="buttons" style="display:flex; justify-content: flex-start;">

                                            <button class="print-button" (click)="print()"
                                                 
                                                ><i
                                                    class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                {{'report.fms.journeyAnalize.yaziciyagonder' |
                                                translate}}
                                            </button>
```

My code ts code:

```
print() {

        html2canvas(document.querySelector("#printArea"), <any>{
            useCors: true,
            allowTaint: false,
            
        }).then(canvas => {
            
            var nWindow = window.open("");

            nWindow.document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            nWindow.focus();
            nWindow.print();
        });

    }
```

[image]